# Modify GAMUserName length in GAM database

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

Is there a way to enlarge GAM UserName's length in GAM database?

The idea is to increase from VarChar(100) to VarChar(256).
I tried by changing domain GAMUserIdentification from Varchar(100) to VarChar(256), but didn't impact GAM database. I also tried changing the database directly, but it still keeps the maximum length of 100.
Is there a way to do it?

I'm in GX Ev3 U2, .Net 4.0 and SQL 2012

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the User's data, to know how to do it see this document http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Extensibility+of+GAM+entity+properties,

This certainly does not work in the context of an offline application. I think the best for this case is that you create a table where you keep the user's information and you can automatically synchronize this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You could change the column definition in the databases, you could change the external object's definition, but there is no way to change the implementation.

Why do you need a user name larger than 100 characters?

Comment: I want to save a SDT.Json in the user name. I need the company, the hired services (productos) and the user level (role) in order to work in a SD offline application. I also need the employeeid but I can get it with the GAMUser.GetExternalId(). So this was an idea to solve the problem...